# Creating an index.js file to export { default }?

Tags: reactjs, export, material-ui

I've been practicing my use of Material UI by looking at some of the example projects posted on the MUI docs page. Some of these projects, like the [React Most Wanted](https://github.com/TarikHuber/react-most-wanted/tree/master/src) or the [React, Material UI, Firebase](https://github.com/Phoqe/react-material-ui-firebase) will create a folder for a component, with an index.js file that will only export the component (e.g. export { default } from './LandingPage').

What is the purpose of doing this instead of simply exporting it in a [LandingPage.js](https://github.com/TarikHuber/react-most-wanted/blob/master/src/pages/LandingPage/LandingPage.js) file like I am used to? Is this a better practice? Thanks

Comment: one of the benefit is you can use  import "./LandingPage".  instead of import "./LandingPage/LandingPage". It's also make it easier if you are moving file around

Comment: Right, but for naming purposes, why not just create a folder called LandingPage, make an index.js file inside that folder, and import it in App.js (where you can just import it as 'import LandingPage from './pages/LandingPage')? 

I realize this may be more of a more React-specific question now, but I assume that keeping your components in folders can be good for testing purposes (as seen in the React, Material UI, Firebase example)

Answer (score 0):

It's purely something implemented for readability, it means that you can have fewer characters in your import statement. However, it isn't something that I generally like to do (or generally see other React developers do). Name your component file after the component, and then create a default export at the bottom of that, you can then import the default export of that file (which will be the component) and use it wherever you want.